# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException in Clipboard.ContainsImage

Tags: c#, .net, exception, clipboard

I've been having this problem for a long while now, and it seems to occur at completely random times. From my understanding, `SEHException` is thrown whenever an interop call fails, but has no .Net Exception thrown with it.

I can get the following stack trace from the exception:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject(Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject()
at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.ContainsImage()
at Dropbox.Dropbox.Menu() in D:\Dev\ClipUpload4\Dropbox\Dropbox.cs:line 109
```

It happens with several different functions in the `Clipboard` class, not just `ContainsImage`.

`ErrorCode` appears to be `-2147467259`, so I don't think that's very helpful.

Any idea what's causing this and how I would fix this?

Comment: It is the way unmanaged code fails.  You certainly do interop with *other* code when you use the clipboard.  But you are looking at the wrong end of it, whatever app put the data on the clipboard is the root source of the problem.  You left no breadcrumbs to have a guess at it, the error code is E_FAIL which doesn't mean anything more than "don't know why".  Disabling anti-malware is usually a good idea was well.

Comment: So the only "real" way to solve this is to just keep calling the functions until it doesn't fail?